# Using knex to read from file and insert into database end in error

Tags: javascript, node.js, knex.js

i have a small piece of code which reads a line from a file, parse it and then inserts into my database.

However after 10 to 12 thousand lines i always get this error:

```
Unhandled rejection Error: Knex: Timeout acquiring a connection. The pool is probably full. Are you missing a .transacting(trx) call?
```

The first file has about 150k lines.

Already tried to manipulate directly the transaction, but had no success.

Any ideas on how to manage resources correctly in order to make all the file?

Here goes the code i'm trying for now:

```js
var fs = require('fs');
var knexfile = require('./knexfile');
var knex = require('knex')(knexfile.production);
var readline = require('readline');

var rl = readline.createInterface({
  terminal : false,
  input : fs.createReadStream('FOO_BAR.TXT') // About 150k lines
});
knex.transaction(function(tx){
  rl.on('line', function(line) { 
    knex("dadosbrutos").insert({ // this table does exists
      AA_DATA : line.substring(0,8),
      BB_DATA : line.substring(8,16),
      CC_DATA : line.substring(36,44)
    }).then(function(){
      tx.commit(); // dies after 12k inserts
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: I would use a promise.each on each line, return the insert and instead of the .then you have just use .transacting(trx)

Comment: Hello @vbranden, it sounds reasonable. Can i promisify the readline?

Answer (score 0):

i created a module to promisify readline https://www.npmjs.com/package/readline-promise, but ill include the source in this post with my answer.

also make sure that you are not exceeding the maximum transaction size for your database.

is there a reason you need to use a transaction? if not, you can just do all of the inserts without a transaction.

```
var fs = require('fs');
var promise = require('bluebird');
var knexfile = require('./knexfile');
var knex = require('knex')(knexfile.production);

// iterates through each line calling callback
function each(cfg) {
    return function(callback) {
        return new promise(function(resolve, reject) {

            // create an array to store callbacks
            var rl, cbs = [];

            // create an interface
            try {
                rl = readline.createInterface(cfg);
            }
            catch(err) {
                return reject(err);
            }

            // handle a new line
            rl.on('line', function(line) {
                cbs.push(callback(line));
            });

            // handle close
            rl.on('close', function() {
                promise.all(cbs).then(function() {
                    resolve({
                        lines: cbs.length
                    });
                })
                .caught(function(err) {
                    reject(err);
                });
            });
        });
    };
}

knex.transaction(function(tx){
    return each({
        terminal : false,
        input : fs.createReadStream('FOO_BAR.TXT')
    })(function(line) {
        return knex("dadosbrutos").insert({ // this table does exists
            AA_DATA : line.substring(0,8),
            BB_DATA : line.substring(8,16),
            CC_DATA : line.substring(36,44)
        }).transacting(tx);
    })
    .then(function() {
        tx.commit();
    });
});
```

Comment: thank you for the module, but sadly it does not solved my problem,  since it keeps all callcabks in memory.

my new approach is to try to generate a file with all sql inserts by calling toString instead the promise.